# Mixed Integer Program with Varying Interest Rates

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I'm currently stuck with a MIP program where the interest rate, i, is based on the number of units produced for Housing Plan A. If the number of plan A houses sold is the highest among all four types then i=1. If the number of plan A houses sold is the second highest, then i=2 and so on up to i=4. The interest rate is basically 2i%. Not really sure how to add constraints that will represent the position of plan A houses and implement the correct interest rate in the objective function. The objective function maximizes the total profit (e.g 50,000A + 40,000B + 70,000C + 80,000D). Any ideas on how to use binary variables to represent position?

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of how you have attempted a solution.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is, is using a permutation matrix `p(i,j)`. I.e.

```
sets 
  i = {A,B,C,D}
  j = {1,2,3,4}

binary variable p(i,j)

# assignment constraints
sum(i,p(i,j))=1
sum(j,p(i,j))=1

# quantities sold
x(j) = sum(i, p(i,j)*x(i))
x(j) >= x(j+1)

# interest rate
r(i) = sum(j, p(i,j)*r(j))
r(j) = 2*j/100
```

Unfortunately the expression `p(i,j)*x(i)` is non-linear. With some effort we can repair this as follows:

```
sets 
  i = {A,B,C,D}
  j = {1,2,3,4}

binary variable p(i,j)
positive variable q(i,j)

# assignment constraints
sum(i,p(i,j))=1
sum(j,p(i,j))=1

# quantities sold
x(j) = sum(i, q(i,j))
x(j) >= x(j+1)

# linearization of q(i,j) = p(i,j)*x(i)
q(i,j) <= p(i,j)*xup(i)
x(i) - xup(i)*(1-p(i,j)) <= q(i,j) <= x(i)

' interest rate
r(i) = 2*sum(j, p(i,j)*j)/100
```

Here `xup(i)` is an upper bound on `x(i)`.

Not a very elegant formulation.

Comment: But isn't the first constraint under quantities sold non-linear since you're multiplying the permutation matrix with x(i) [the quantity you are also solving for]?

Comment: Darn, you are right. Could be linearized easily but that makes this thing rather complicated.

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out, but seems a little difficult to linearize the Ranking constraint since both quantities and binary variables are unknown. Any ideas?